# Как вызвать метод из конструктора в C#

Tags: c#, конструктор

Пытаюсь написать код, который бы перегружал конструкторы вместе с методами и, в зависимости от типа поступающей переменной mass_str реализовывал бы необходимый мне метод, но не могу нигде найти, как вызвать нужный мне метод. Пока код выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка CS1061  "Set" не содержит определения "fillset", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "fillset", принимающий тип "Set" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Сама переменная mass_str получает на вход из текстового файла цифры 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Вот сам код:

```
class Set
{
    public Set(string[] mass_str)
    {
        void fillset(string[] mass_str)
        {
            SortedSet<char> s1 = new SortedSet<char>();
            char x;
            for (int i = 0; i < mass_str.Length; i++)
            {
                x = Convert.ToChar(mass_str[i]);
                s1.Add(x);
            }
        }
    }

    public Set(double[] mass_str)
    {
        void fillset(double[] mass_str)
        {
            SortedSet<double> s1 = new SortedSet<double>();
            double x;
            for (int i = 0; i < mass_str.Length; i++)
            {
                x = Convert.ToDouble(mass_str[i]);
                s1.Add(x);
            }
        }
    }

    public Set(int[] mass_str)
    {
        void fillset(int[] mass_str)
        {
            SortedSet<int> s1 = new SortedSet<int>();
            int x;
            for (int i = 0; i < mass_str.Length; i++)
            {
                x = Convert.ToInt32(mass_str[i]);
                s1.Add(x);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("..\\..\\..\\Заданное.txt");
        string[] delimeters_0 = { " ", "," };
        string[] mass_str = sr.ReadLine().Split(delimeters_0, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        Set newset1 = new Set(mass_str);
        newset1.fillset()
    }
}
```

Код с int[]:

```
class Set
{
    public Set(string[] mass_str)
    {
        fillset(mass_str);
    }

    public Set(double[] mass_str)
    {
        fillset(mass_str);
    }

    public Set(int[] mass_str)
    {
        fillset(mass_str);
    }

    public void fillset(string[] mass_str)
    {
        SortedSet<char> s1 = new SortedSet<char>();
        char x;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            x = Convert.ToChar(mass_str[i]);
            s1.Add(x);
        }
    }

    void fillset(double[] mass_str)
    {
        SortedSet<double> s1 = new SortedSet<double>();
        double x;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            x = Convert.ToDouble(mass_str[i]);
            s1.Add(x);
        }
    }

    void fillset(int[] mass_str)
    {
        SortedSet<int> s1 = new SortedSet<int>();
        int x;
        for (int i = 0; i <9; i++)
        {
            x = Convert.ToInt32(mass_str[i]);
            s1.Add(x);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("..\\..\\..\\Заданное.txt");
        string[] delimeters_0 = { " ", "," };
        string[] stringmass = sr.ReadLine().Split(delimeters_0, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        
        int[] mass_str = new int[9];
        for (int i=0;  i < 9; i++)
        {
            mass_str[i] = Convert.ToInt32(stringmass[i]);
        }

        Set newset1 = new Set(mass_str);
        newset1.fillset(mass_str);
    }
}
```

Comment: А это вообще легально объявлять метод внутри другого метода/конструктора?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вполне себе легально https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions Но всё равно у автора чёрти-что.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как минимум, это должно выглядеть так:

```
class Set
{
    public Set(string[] mass_str)
    {
        fillset(mass_str);
    }

    public Set(double[] mass_str)
    {
        fillset(mass_str);
    }

    public Set(int[] mass_str)
    {
        fillset(mass_str);
    }

    void fillset(string[] mass_str)
    {
        SortedSet<char> s1 = new SortedSet<char>();
        char x;
        for (int i = 0; i < mass_str.Length; i++)
        {
            x = Convert.ToChar(mass_str[i]);
            s1.Add(x);
        }
    }

    void fillset(double[] mass_str)
    {
        SortedSet<double> s1 = new SortedSet<double>();
        double x;
        for (int i = 0; i < mass_str.Length; i++)
        {
            x = Convert.ToDouble(mass_str[i]);
            s1.Add(x);
        }
    }

    void fillset(int[] mass_str)
    {
        SortedSet<int> s1 = new SortedSet<int>();
        int x;
        for (int i = 0; i < mass_str.Length; i++)
        {
            x = Convert.ToInt32(mass_str[i]);
            s1.Add(x);
        }
    }
}
```

А дальше ещё... Можно обобщённый класс сделать `class Set<T>` или обобщённый метод `void fillset<T>(T[] mass_str)`.

Работает:

```
using System;
static class Programm {
    class Set {
        public void fillset(string[] mass_str) {}
        public void fillset(int[] mass_str) {}
    }
    static void Main() {
        var a1 = new Set(); a1.fillset(new string[] {"a", "b"});
        var a2 = new Set(); a1.fillset(new int[] {1, 2});
    }
}
```

Comment: Set newset1 = new Set(mass_str);
newset1.fillset(mass_str)
При таком вызове методе, если тип mass_str - string[] , то все правильно работает, но если я меняю тип на int[] , на строке newset1.fillset(mass_str) вылезает ошибка: 
"не удается неявно преобразовать из int[] в string[]"
Не подскажете, почему так? Разве при передаче массива типа int[] в конструктор, он не должен выбирать конструктор, который принимает int[] mass_str ?

Comment: Покажите, как вы этого добились - добавьте в свой вопрос. Я добавил в ответ код, который работает.

Comment: А зачем вы запускаете fillset после конструктора, если передаёте конструктору эти данные (и он заполняет что-то там)?

Comment: Добавил код с массивом int[]

Comment: Вы забыли объявить void fillset(double[] mass_str) и void fillset(int[] mass_str) как public.

Comment: А почему у вас появилась фиксированная длина вместо mass_str.Length?

Comment: Для конвертации используйте `mass_str = Array.ConvertAll(stringmass, Convert.ToInt32);` вместо вашего цикла.